# Robot Framework - Run Chrome with system proxy

Tags: selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Ok so I got this code:

```
*** Variables ***
${URL_BASE}       www.google.com
${field}          //*[@id="lst-ib"]
${text}           selenium
${buttonSearch}    //*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]
${ResultSearchLink1}    //*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h3/a

*** Test Cases ***
init
Set global variable    ${URL_BASE}    http://www.google.fr

google
open browser    http://www.google.com    Chrome    desired_capabilities=proxyType:manual,httpProxy:http://proxy1.proj.aql.fr:3128
```

After I run the keywords "Open Browser To Google", firefox opens and can't even open the url.

I got the error: ERR_PROXY_CONNEXION_FAILED

How can i configure open the browser with a proxy?

Comment: Your description mentions a keyword named `Open Browser To Google` but your code shows no such keyword.

Comment: I means after this line "open browser    http://www.google.com    Chrome    desired_capabilities=proxyType:manual,httpProxy:http://proxy1.proj.aql.fr:3128"